# BGW Multiplication: Linearizing the polynomial

Tags: secret-sharing, multiparty-computation

I have some trouble understanding the linearization of the degree `2t` polynomial generated by multiplication in BGW. It would be great if someone could decode this linearization in simple terms from a `2t` degree polynomial to a `t` degree polynomial.

I've understood that in multiplication, we calculate `r(x) = p(x)q(x)` but this means that `r(x)` is a polynomial of degree `2t`. How is this polynomial distributed linearly in the circuit?

Addition in BGW is easy to understand but multiplication has been difficult to comprehend.

Reference: https://www.csa.iisc.ac.in/~arpita/SecureComputation15/Lecture18.pdf

Comment: define BGW for completeness please. And give a link if applicable

Comment: does this work fine?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what part of [my answer to your similar question](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/80230/bgw-multiplication-how-does-it-work/80235#80235) you had issues understanding? Asking a follow up question is completely fine, but I don't know what part of the answer to write differently.

Comment: Hi @Mark, I didn't get how the Vandermonde matrix was created and how exactly the `2t` degree polynomial becomes `t` degree in the end and how the linear case works. I know how Shamir's scheme works but I'm still finding it hard to comprehend this.

Comment: I've implemented the construction of the matrix that BGW uses in [this code](https://repl.it/repls/ForcefulConfusedSystemresource). Note that it uses real (or more properly floating point arithmetic) instead of Finite Field arithmetic, so there are some rounding errors.

Playing around with those functions may help you understand more concretely that these things work (for example, there is explicit code implementing the creation of the Vandermonde matrix, and the code responsible for the `2t` degree polynomial becoming `t` degree is the `proj` matrix in the `trunc_matrix` function).

Comment: Understanding *why* the above all works on a conceptual level is slightly more difficult. I managed to feel pressed for space (while writing a quite long answer) on your previous question. I would suggest breaking down the problem of understanding BGW arithmetic into "How to take shares of a polynomial and "truncate" them via a linear operation" and "How to securely compute a linear operation of shares". All of my comments have been towards this first point.

Comment: Thanks for the code @Mark, I'll go through this

Comment: Just a really small doubt in the code....what does `@` mean ? My guess is `*` but I just want to be sure :)

Comment: @rakshitnaidu That's pythons "matrix multiplication operator".

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help @Mark